# How to reuse RABL partial templates by keeping conventions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, rabl

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and the [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) gem. I would like to reuse templates by rendering the `show.json.rabl` view from the `index.json.rabl` and keep convention stated at [jsonapi.org](http://jsonapi.org) (source: [RABL documentation](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Conforming-to-jsonapi.org-format)).

That is, I have the following files:

```
# index.json.rabl
collection @articles => :articles
attributes :id, :title, :...

# show.json.rabl
collection [@article] => :articles
attributes :id, :title, :...
```

Since for each `article` instance the `index.json.rabl` renders the same attributes as for the `show.json.rabl` I would like to reuse the latter as partial template, or (maybe) to extend the first.

What I would like to output is:

```
# index JSON output
{"articles":[{"id":1,"title":"Sample 1","...":...},{"id":2,"title":"Sample 2","...":...},{"id":3,"title":"Sample 3","...":...}]}

# show JSON output
{"articles":[{"id":1,"title":"Sample 1","...":...}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a neat way:

## things/base.rabl:

```
attributes :id, :title
child(:another_child, :object_root => false) { attributes :id, :title }
```

## things/show.rabl:

```
object @thing
extends 'things/base'
```

## things/index.rabl:

```
collection @things
extends 'things/base'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extends - https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Reusing-templates

```
object @post

child :categories do
  extends "categories/show"
end
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete answer including an example with `show.json.rabl` and `index.json.rabl` views.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble interpreting what I needed to do from https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Reusing-templates but finally figured it out.  For me, I had files structured like this: (names changed to protect the innocent ;) )

```
/app/controllers/api/my/boring_things_controller.rb
/app/views/api/my/boring_things/index.json.rabl
/app/controllers/api/my/interesting_things_controller.rb
/app/views/api/my/interesting_things/index.json.rabl
```

**boring_things/index.json.rabl** looked like this (except for real, it had a LOT more attributes):

```
collection @boring_things, :root => :things, :object_root => false
attributes :id,
           :name,
           :created_at,
           :updated_at
```

And **interesting_things/index.json.rabl** looked *ALMOST* identical:

```
collection @interesting_things, :root => :things, :object_root => false
attributes :id,
           :name,
           :created_at,
           :updated_at
```

I wanted to reuse just the attribute parts.  The confusing part to me about https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Reusing-templates was that I didn't really think I needed a 'node', and I didn't think I needed 'child' either because I wanted the attributes at the top level, not as a child object.  But it turns out I did need 'child'.  Here's what I ended up with:

```
/app/controllers/api/my/boring_things_controller.rb
/app/views/api/my/boring_things/index.json.rabl
/app/controllers/api/my/interesting_things_controller.rb
/app/views/api/my/interesting_things/index.json.rabl
/app/views/api/my/shared/_things.json.rabl
```

**_things.json.rabl** is this:

```
attributes :id,
           :name,
           :created_at,
           :updated_at
```

**boring_things/index.json.rabl** is now this:

```
child @boring_things, :root => :things, :object_root => false do
  extends "api/my/shared/_things"
end
```

and **interesting_things/index.json.rabl** is now this:

```
child @interesting_things, :root => :things, :object_root => false do
  extends "api/my/shared/_things"
end
```

So for you, instead of rendering **show** from **index**, I'd try doing something where you extract article attributes out into a rabl file shared by index and show.  In the same directory where your **show.json.rabl** and **index.json.rabl** are (I'm assuming it's views/articles/index.json.rabl and views/articles/show.json.rabl), create a "**_article_attributes.json.rabl**" file.  Sorry I don't have your exact setup so I can't try it out myself syntactically, but it should be something like this in your **index.json.rabl**:

```
child @articles do
  extends "articles/_article_attributes"
end
```

[A side note: Another thing that tripped me up when I was doing this was that since my shared file was in a sibling-directory to the different rabl files that used them and I was ***trying to use a relative path and that did NOT work***.  Instead I had to use the path starting with whatever's under "app/views" (i.e. "extends 'api/my/shared/_things'" not "extends '../shared/_things'").  That was a weird situation and I won't go into why we did it that way, but if you can it's better to have the shared file in the same directory as your index and show, like you're doing.]